# Code wont store two zero's when input by the user, instead, stores a single 0

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Please enter the minute(s) that you finished on (MM): ");
    endMin = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

When i put in "00" as an input for minutes, it only stores "0" in the variable.

Comment: You're confusing a number with its String representation.

Comment: `input.nextLine()` may well be returning `"00"`, but `Integer.parseInt` returns an `int`, not a string. That `int` will contain the value 0, which when rendered as a string in standard form is `"0"`.

Comment: Would setting the types of the variable as string and then parsing them as an int later work?

Comment: Passing it back to what? Remember, we have only the information above to work with.

Comment: @Maeleh we cannot say. We do not know your application. The value of the `int` will be `0`.

Comment: These are my variables and their types:

`int startHour, startMin, endHour, endMin;
 string day = ""; `

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you will want to keep the number input as a String. You already do that, so in order to also have an int you can actually work with you could have `endMin` remain a String (instead of converting it to an int) and something like `endMinInt` be that value converted to an int. That way you can still do the calculations you need, but you can also tell the user exactly what they entered later on (which is the only reason I can think of why this would be worth doing)

```
    String endMin;
    int endMinInt;
    System.out.println("Please enter the minute(s) that you finished on (MM): ");
    endMin = input.nextLine();
    endMinInt = Integer.parseInt(endMin);
```